# What's wrong with this Python code? PermissionError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, permissions

This program is supposed to be able to download the contents from an http: URL and save it to a user's directory of choice.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

def run_user_interface() -> None:
    url = _choose_url()
    if len(url) == 0:
    return
    else:
        print()
        save_path = _choose_save_path()

        if len(save_path) == 0:
            return
        else:
            _download_url(url, save_path)

def _choose_url() -> str:
    print('Choose a URL to download (press Enter or Return to quit)')
    return input('URL: ').strip()


def _choose_save_path() -> str:
    print('Choose where you\'d like to save the file you download')
    return input('Path: ').strip()


def _download_url(url_to_download: str, file_path: str) -> None:
    response = None
    file_to_save = None

    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_to_download)
        file_to_save = open(file_path, 'wb')
        file_to_save.write(response.read())

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('Failed to download contents of URL')
    print('Status code: {}'.format(e.code))
    print()

    finally:
        if file_to_save != None:
            file_to_save.close()

        if response != None:
        response.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_user_interface()
```

Executing the program on my friend's computer works fine. However, when I execute it on my computer, I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\garci\Desktop\ICS_32_Winter_2020\new_download_file.py", line 63, in <module>
run_user_interface()

  File "C:\Users\garci\Desktop\ICS_32_Winter_2020\new_download_file.py", line 20, in run_user_interface
_download_url(url, save_path)

  File "C:\Users\garci\Desktop\ICS_32_Winter_2020\new_download_file.py", line 40, in _download_url
file_to_save = open(file_path, 'wb')

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\garci\\Desktop\\ICS_32_Winter_2020'
```

How could I fix this permission error? Thank you.

Comment: Run your python code as adminstrator

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 reasons why this could be happening:

- The file is being used while being written. To get around this, **CLOSE THE FILE**
- The directory you're writing to is write protected (highly unlikely) unless you did this yourself.
- Not enough permissions are granted to python to read/write files. To overcome this, **use Windows Key + X and then press A, which shall open a cmd promt with admin priveleges. Change directory and try running the script.**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your program is not allowed to write to this specific location on your PC.

Change the permissions for the folder `C:\Users\garci\Desktop\ICS_32_Winter_2020` and your program should run fine.

A simple way of doing so (on Windows) is to find your directory in the file explorer, right click on the folder, select **Properties**, and then open the **Security** tab. From there, you can modify the read/write permissions for the folder.